# How do you share data between a parent and forked child process in Python?

Tags: python, fork, share

I'm pretty sure one would do this using the os.plock(op) function, but I have no idea how. Also, if there's a better way, I'd be grateful to find out. Code snippets are very welcome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess) replaces os.popen, os.system, os.spawn, popen2 and commands. A [simple example for piping](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess#replacing-shell-pipe-line) would be:

```
p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

You could also use a [memory mapped file](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html) with the flag=MAP_SHARED for shared memory between processes.

[multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) abstracts both [pipes](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) and [shared memory](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) and provides a higher level interface. Taken from the Processing documentation:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def f(conn):
    conn.send([42, None, 'hello'])
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    print parent_conn.recv()   # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    p.join()
```

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html) module new in python 2.6  (also available for earlier versions a [pyprocessing](http://pyprocessing.berlios.de/)

Here's an example from the docs illustrating passing information using a pipe for instance:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def f(conn):
    conn.send([42, None, 'hello'])
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    print parent_conn.recv()   # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    p.join()
```

Comment: You could mention the Value, Array and the Manager classes provided by multiprocessing, which allow data sharing: http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty much Python-independent!  It's a classic example of Unix interprocess communication.  One good option is to use `popen()` to open a pipe between the parent and child processes, and pass data/messages back and forth along the pipe.

Take a look at the [`subprocess` module](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-subprocess.html), which can set up the necessary pipes automatically while spawning child processes.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options: `os.popen*` in the `os` module, or you can use the `subprocess` module to the same effect. The Python manual has pretty documentation and examples for [popen](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-popen2.html) and [subprocess](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-subprocess.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing low-level operating system forking and really want to avoid using pipes, it is possible to use shared memory-mapped files as well. This is not nearly as nice as using `subprocess` or `popen` pipes, but including the answer for completeness...

There's a [full example here](https://blog.schmichael.com/2011/05/15/sharing-python-data-between-processes-using-mmap/), but basically you can combine the [os](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) file handling and [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) modules:

```python
import mmap, os, tempfile
fd, tmpfile = tempfile.mkstemp()
os.write(fd, '\x00' * mmap.PAGESIZE)
os.lseek(fd, 0, os.SEEK_SET)
child_pid = os.fork()
if child_pid:
    buf = mmap.mmap(fd, mmap.PAGESIZE, mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.PROT_READ)
    os.waitpid(child_pid, 0)
    child_message = buf.readline()
    print(child_message)
    os.close(fd)
else:
    buf = mmap.mmap(fd, mmap.PAGESIZE, mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.PROT_WRITE)
    buf.write('testing\n')
    os.close(fd)
```