# Any way to have a shared data structure with child process?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am using subprocess.Popen to create child process out of my code. Here, I read a file, process it with new values and dump values in another file. Then I use the subprocess.Popen to start a child process which consumes the new file and process them.

Is there any way for the subprocess.Popen to share data(at least one string variable) with the Child process? I will not require the processed data with the parent process. So even if the option removes the data from parent process, it is fine.

[UPDATE] after reading the comments and looking into the communicate method
This is what I am facing:

1. Read a file in the parent process
2. Do some formatting that is required for Child process
3. Dump the processed data into a file
4. Call the child process, which consumes the processed file and perform
5. Move on to do formatting of the next file as this is not dependent on the child process

Instead of dumping into a file and read the file in the child process, is there any way to pass the processed data to the child process directly? The file contains lots of special characters and so I think it would be hard to read the entire content through stdin of the child process. Also in my case, I would rather continue without waiting for the child process as the number of files that need to be processed is higher. That's the main reason I went with subprocess. Else, I could do it in the main process itself. Am I woried too much about file read and write over head? Or is there a way to give data to the child process without giving a file write/read?

Comment: Please ask any info required and I will be happy to add/share about this.

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218935/how-do-you-share-data-between-a-parent-and-forked-child-process-in-python)

Comment: You can use threading with a thread safe Queue. You might want to look into that. Also look into the communicate method.https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Thanks for the links. However, is there any way to share a data without making the parent wait for the child to complete?

Comment: If the parent doesn't care about the output of the child, why not just pass the required data as arguments to the process? You can fit ~10MB worth of characters in there depending on OS. EX: `subprocess.Popen(['myProcess','My data'])`.

Comment: Why you are using subprocess? Is it yours apps or child process is built-in app? What's your OS?
I'm thinking you take wrong tool for your purpose, and multiprocessing will be better for your aim.

Comment: @aruisdante The child process is an application from another team. It only takes the file path as an argument. That's a good suggestion. I will check with that team to take the contents rather than the file path. But my concern is that the processed file might have both the type of quotes and whether it will be feasible for the CLA.

Comment: @Jimilian I am using subprocess because that is the only module I know of. I will be happy to switch to any other built-in module as it is entirely in my control. Both the apps are created within my company but by different teams. Could we pass data through multiprocessing module?

Comment: @thiruvenkadam, are both coded in python?

Comment: @Jimilian yes. Both are python modules. Sorry for the very very delayed response.